# how do I get into the didSelectAnnotationView method?

Tags: objective-c

Im tryin to make a mapview where I can get a location and its coordinates then send it to another view.
I tried to use didSelectAnnotationView to send the information.
But for some reason I'm not getting into the didSelectAnnotationView method.

Can someone tell me?

Or if I am doing something wrong. What method should I use?

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set the delegate (a MKMapViewDelegate) on your MKMapView ?

Comment: yes I did, but I have used another method which does workL=) - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

Comment: hi does you get any solution for the problem??

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you add the delegate on the interface, and the method header names are correct.

Example:

```
@interface MapperViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view;

@end
```

This code should fire when user taps on pin head:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)mapView2
{
    MapAnnotation *annotation = mapView2.annotation;
    NSString *temp = annotation.title;
}
```

Comment: hi what is this `MapAnnotaion`?